# Swift detect and set wkwebview to respect hardware mute switch

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

In my app i use a wkwebview to display web content

In the app if i set the hardware mute switch on the sound in the app stops but the sound in the controller class which hold the wkwebview still play.

How can i set it so it will respect the mute switch?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a WKWebView bug: http://www.openradar.me/28716885